# pug/firebase: add users from input to firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pug

I'm trying to add some users from a form to my firebase database. For that I've already linked up firebase config into my `main.pug`.
But nothing works, I've looked up everywhere and I'm pretty lost. 
Need your help and sorry if the code is ugly.

There is my Addform.pug:

```
div
    h2 Add Form
    form#addForm

    div
        label(for='username') Username
        input(type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username')#username

    div
        label(for='name') Name
        input(type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name')#name

    div
        label(for='description') Description
        textarea(type='text' name='description' placeholder='Description')#description

    div
        label(for='email') Email
        input(type='email' name='email' placeholder='Email')#email

    div
        label(for='password') Password
        input(type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password')#password

    div
        input(type='submit' value="ADD" onclick='writeUserData')
        div
            a(href='../src/editForm.html') Modify
```

And there my sxript:

```
// Variables
let username = document.querySelector('#username').value;
let name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
let email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
let password = document.querySelector('#password').value;
let description = document.querySelector('#description').value;
let users = document.querySelector('#users').value;
const submit = document.querySelector('#submit');

// Get a reference to the database service
const userRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Users');

// Add users
const writeUserData = () => {

    userRef.push({
       username,
       name,
       description,
       email,
       password
    });

    console.log(username, name, description, email, password);
}

// Display users
userRef.on('value', function (snap) {
    console.log(snap.val());
    users.innerText = JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 2);
});

// Delete user
function deleteUser() {
   userRef.key('Users').remove();
}
```

It seems that I can't get the value, it's throwing me one error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

Also I can neither see the hard coded data from firebase nor can delete my users.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your JavaScript selection code.  `document.querySelector("#xyz")` is looking for the element with ID xyz. You have named inputs but would need to give your input elements corresponding IDs as well. An example would be

```
    input#email(type='email', name='email', placeholder='Email')#email
```

Notice you also need to add a comma before the name attribute

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) In this case, ``input(type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username')#username``I gave the id ``username`` and I've solved my problem with a ``window.onload``